# How to keep CardView drop shadow aligned on transformation of view?

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter

I'm using a CardView within a FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android.support.v7.cardview:cardElevation="12dp"
    android.support.v7.cardview:cardCornerRadius="24dp"
    android.support.v7.cardview:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
```

On API level 21, when I drag a card that is off screen onto the screen, the drop shadow of the CardView is misaligned, as if it's trailing behind the drag, until I release my finger in which the shadow repositions itself to center.

On API's less than 21, it works fine!

I'm looking for a way to avoid this shadow glitch on API level 21. I found that disabling hardware layers for the ViewPager fixes it, but leads to greatly reduced scrolling performance. Note that I am using a custom rotation transformation while paging through the items in the ViewPager.

Is there any way to fix this shadow glitch without disabling hardware layers?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the new CardView Library? Maybe you should change the 21 in your build.gradle to 23.

Comment: Yep, I'm using the latest libraries in my project. I guess it's just a glitch.